# Stuck on handling duplicate records on MongoDb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongodb table with unique index on "userID"

```
$collection = $db->databsename->collectionName;
$userId = 1;
$lastTimeOnline = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
echo $lastTimeOnline; // output : 2016-02-22 05:20:53
$doc = array(
    "userID" => $userId,
    "lastTimeOnline" => $lastTimeOnline,
    "displayName" => ''
);
$a = $collection->insert($doc); // This will successfully insert



sleep(1);
$lastTimeOnline = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
echo "\n".$lastTimeOnline;// output : 2016-02-22 05:20:54
$lastTimeOnline = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$doc = array(
    "userID" => $userId,
    "lastTimeOnline" => $lastTimeOnline,
    "displayName" => ''
);
$a = $collection->insert($doc); // This will pass but not insert any thing
var_dump($db->lastError());
```

As expected last line will yield below error

```
array(5) {
      'connectionId' =>
      int(101)
      'err' =>
      string(88) "E11000 duplicate key error collection: databsename.collectionName index: userID_1 dup key: { : 1 }"
      'code' =>
      int(11000)
      'n' =>
      int(0)
      'ok' =>
      double(1)
    }
```

**Requirement**
I need 2nd insert to replace first. i.e "2016-02-22 05:20:54" should replace "2016-02-22 05:20:53".

**Solution:**
Do i need to check if error exists then update the record or a better sol is available?

Comment: use update with upsert=true

Comment: @Undefined_variable dont u think upsert will be slow ?

Comment: Checking for duplicates and then again doing update/insert will involve 2 network calls which will further slow down your apllication